# Calculating Amazon S3 Bucket Size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jets3t

My requirement is to calculate individual bucket sizes on Amazon s3. Currently am doing it using **JetS3T** library.

Am using the **ThreadedStorageService.listObjects()** method to find the size of each individual object and then sum it up. Even though the method uses multiple threads, its taking a long time to list all the objects in the bucket. Like 45 mins for 80,000 objects.

Is there any other way to calculate the bucket size in a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your thread count is low since this is so slow for you, try bumping it up. You should easily be able to use something like 100 threads to do the work.